# Facebook login using python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to automate the Facebook login using python requests library, here is my code :

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

EMAIL = 'useremail@domain.com'
PASS = 'userpassword'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php'
LOGIN_URL_MAIN = 'https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=100'
ACCEPTED_RESPONSE_TYPE = 'text/html; charset="utf-8"'
COOKIE_NAME = 'datr'
COOKIE_DIVIDER = '","'
COOKIE_LEN = 24
_data = {}
cookie_lst = []
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Cookie': '467x635',        
        'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform' : '"Windows"',
        'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform-Version':'"10.0.0"',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'navigate',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
        'Sec-Fetch-User':'?1',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
        'Viewport-Width': '467'
    }

session = requests.Session()
_source = session.get(LOGIN_URL, headers=headers)

def return_cookies(url):
    '''
    Attempt to fetch the cookie from /login.php


        { lgndim = eyJ3IjoxMzY2LCJoIjo3NjgsImF3IjoxMzY2LCJhaCI6NzM4LCJjIjoyNH0=
        lgnjs = the current time } = [+] This remains constant

         { ab_test_data = AAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAV//VAAAABDAA } 
         = [!] This doesn't remain constant ! 
        
    '''
    if _source.headers.get('Content-Type') == ACCEPTED_RESPONSE_TYPE:
        if _source.text.index('datr') != -1:
            split_scr = _source.text.split(COOKIE_NAME+COOKIE_DIVIDER)
            datr_cookie = split_scr[1][:COOKIE_LEN]
    for c in _source.cookies:
        if c.name or c.value:
            cookie_lst.append(c.name+'='+c.value)
    cookie_lst.append('datr='+datr_cookie)
    cookie_lst.append('wd=467x635')
    cookie_txt = "; ".join(cookie_lst)
    session.close()
    return cookie_txt

def login(email, password):
    
    bs = BeautifulSoup(_source.text, 'html5lib')
    _hiddeninputs = bs.findAll('input', attrs={'type': 'hidden'})
    for _hiddeninput in _hiddeninputs:
        if _hiddeninput.get('name') != None:
            _data[_hiddeninput.get('name')] = _hiddeninput.get('value')
        if _hiddeninput.get('value') == None:
            _data[_hiddeninput.get('name')] = ''
    _data['ab_test_data'] = 'AAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVA/A/AAAABCAA'
    _data['lgndim'] = 'eyJ3IjoxMzY2LCJoIjo3NjgsImF3IjoxMzY2LCJhaCI6NzM4LCJjIjoyNH0='
    _data['lgnjs'] = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
    _data['timezone'] = '-330'
    _data['email'] = email
    _data.pop(None)
    print(_data['had_password_prefilled'])
    headers['Cookie'] = return_cookies(LOGIN_URL)
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    headers['Origin'] = 'https://www.facebook.com'
    headers['Referer'] = LOGIN_URL
    time.sleep(5)
    _data['encpass'] = f'#PWD_BROWSER:5:{int(datetime.now().timestamp())+200}:{password}'

    response = session.post(LOGIN_URL_MAIN, data=_data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
    print(response.status_code)

    # time.sleep(5)
    for h in headers:
        print(h)
    print('\n')
    for d in _data:
        print(d)

login(EMAIL, PASS)
```

It does not give proper response in the **response.text** which should say whether login was success or not. Please help me out !

I tried several codes but this one I've made it by self by researching and experimenting the login process through browser and intercepting the network packets.

Comment: What do you see the output of print(response.status_code)  ?

Comment: I'm getting 200 status code, if the login process was correctly done, regardless of successfully or unsuccessfull login it should show 302 redirect but I'm getting 200 still.